# How can I stop or pause an SKAction playing music? - Swift

Tags: function, audio, swift

I need to know how to stop or pause an SKAction that is playing the theme song for my game, when the pause button is pressed. The code I am using is meant to remove the action when the button is pressed but it is not working. This code is in my GameScene class.

```
func startGameMusic() {
    runAction (SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("theme.mp3", waitForCompletion: true), withKey: "themeSong")
}

func stopGameMusic() {
    self.removeActionForKey ("themeSong")
}
```

The stopGameMusic function is called when the pause button is pressed in the GameViewController class.

```
@IBAction func didPause(sender: UIButton) {
    if self.scene.paused == false{
        self.scene.stopTicking()
        self.scene.paused = true
        self.scene.stopGameMusic()        
    }
}
```

or:

```
 @IBAction func didPause(sender: UIButton) {
     if self.scene.paused == false{
         self.scene.stopTicking()
         self.scene.paused = true
         self.scene.removeActionForKey("themeSong")
     }
 }
```

Comment: How do you know if `didPause()` is being called?  Is it connected to a button's action?  Add an NSLog() or a debugger breakpoint to confirm `didPause()` is called.

Comment: yes, did pause is being called because the items on screen move with each tick, and they stop moving when you press the button which calls the function to stopTicking()

Comment: any help? im not sure why the function isnt being removed

Comment: In your `startGameMusic` your specified `waitForCompletion:true`.  Maybe you can't pause because the player is playing until completion - without interruptions.  Try `false` and then see if you can pause.

Comment: no unfortunately that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Just finished coding a pause button myself; looks like the Swiftris demo.   I did it from the view controller as opposed to the scene.  The sounds that are played once are coded in the view controller, like game over, so why not keep them all in one spot?  I added these few lines of code as far as the audio:

```
import AVFoundation
```

then inside the class function...

```
var backgroundAudio = AVPlayer(URL:NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("theme",ofType:"mp3")!))

var gameStatus:Bool = true
```

then inside of my IBAction function linked to a pause button...

```
if(gameStatus == true {

    scene.stopTicking()

    backgroundAudio.pause()

    gameStatus = false

else {

     scene.startTicking()

     backgroundAudio.play()

     gameStatus = true

}
```

explanation: AVFoundation gives you a whole lot of Audio/Visual Tools
The gameStatus variable lets me know if its paused or not. true = on
If it's on and pause is pressed, the scene quits ticking, audio pauses, and gameStatus goes to off.
If game status is false, the button activates the scene timer and picks up the audio where it left off.  gameStatus is then set to true as the game has resumed.  Didn't add the run forever functionality yet of the theme song.